# SQL - Subtract the Sum of Two Groups Between Two Tables (Simple) (MS Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to get the total population from each state from table A and then subtract the change in population from Table B. Grouping by State. I don't understand why my query isn't working:

```
**TABLE A**                              **TABLE B**
NY    New York    10,000             NY    New York    -3000
NY    Syracuse     5,000             NY    Syracuse     5000
PA    Phila       12,000             PA    Phila        1000
PA    Erie        11,000             PA    Erie         4000


SELECT a.State, a.City, 
    (SELECT Sum(a.population) FROM a) -
    (SELECT SUM(b.popchange) FROM b)
FROM a
GROUP BY a.state
ORDER BY a.state;
```

Comment: Remove `city` from the `select`.  Then the results will not be correct, but at least the query will run.

Comment: It runs with city, and I need the city in the output. I just need to combine the values per state and city from table a and table b

Comment: . . Then you are not using MS Access.  You don't have `City` in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never Brought table b into your "from" statement. you need something like this:

```
SELECT a.State,
    Sum(a.population) -
    SUM(b.popchange)
FROM a inner join b on a.State = b.State and a.city = b.city
GROUP BY a.state
ORDER BY a.state;
```

Edit: If table B has fewer records than A, then try this:

```
SELECT sumA.state, sumA.popSum - Nz(sumB.popSum,0) AS SumOfPopulation
FROM (SELECT Sum(a.population) AS popSum, a.state FROM a GROUP BY a.state)  AS sumA 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT Sum(b.popChange) AS popSum, b.state FROM b GROUP BY b.state)  AS sumB 
ON sumA.state = sumB.state;
```

It sums them separately, and does a left join because table B might not have a value when table A does.

Edit: To group by city as well, you just need to add it to the two group by statements:

```
SELECT sumA.state,sumA.city, [sumA].[popSum]-Nz([sumB].[popSum],0) AS SumOfPopulation
FROM (SELECT Sum(a.population) AS popSum, a.state,a.city FROM a GROUP BY a.state, a.city)  AS sumA 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT Sum(b.popChange) AS popSum, b.state,b.city FROM b GROUP BY b.state, b.city)  AS sumB 
ON sumA.state = sumB.state;
```

Comment: Still won't work since a and b are referred to in a subquery and thus arent joined there. Edit: you fixed it

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth  Sorry, the problem with writing answers too quickly. I changed it now.

Comment: Guess you gotta be fast :) the only reason that I didn't answer the question was because you already did, and if you were 1 min later @Rahul would've been first

Comment: This runs, but it is only giving me 1 state with a huge total

Comment: @SeanKelly I just added city to the join statement. Try it now. It should work  fine if both tables contain the same states and cities...

Comment: Still not giving me what I need. This is only outputting the cities listed in the population change table (which is much shorter than the total pop table). I just need to check table B for changes and then agregate with table A to produce the current population

Comment: Ok, then you need to do subQueries for the sums, grouped by state, and add the sums together.

Comment: Works wonderfully, but I also need to have the city listed in the end result, as each state has multiple cities. where can i also add a GROUP BY city in this query?

Comment: You add it to the two "group by" statements. See my edit,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147834/discussion-between-quark-and-sean-kelly).

Comment: @Quark You rock

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the extra column from `SELECT` which not used in `GROUP BY`. You query should be

```
SELECT a.State, 
    Sum(a.population) - SUM(b.popchange) as diff_population
FROM a JOIN b ON a.state = b.state 
GROUP BY a.state
ORDER BY a.state;
```